# Why does the H1 tag not align with the top of a div?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make so the H1 is vertically aligned with the other divs.

[image]

This is the code.

```css
header {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000032; 
}
  header div {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0; 
  }
  header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
  }
  header #social {
    float: left; 
  }
  header li img {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  header img {
    display: block; 
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block; 
  }
  header h1 a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none; 
  }
  header #menu {
    float: right; 
  }

main {
  height: 100vh; 
}
```

```html
<header class="row--no-gutter">
    <div class="col--1-of-3">
      <ul>
        <li id="social"><a href="#"><img src="../img/_f_logo_online/png/FB-f-Logo__blue_100.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li id="social"><a href="#"><img src="../img\Twitter_Starter_Kit\Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square/Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square_Color.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
        <li id="social"></li>
        <li id="social"></li>
      </ul>
    </div><div class="col--1-of-3">
      <h1><a href="#">Lorem.</a></h1>
    </div><div class="col--1-of-3">
      <ul>
        <li id="menu">Om</li>
        <li id="menu">lorem1</li>
        <li id="menu">ipsun</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
```

But as you can see on the picture the H1 does not align with the top. Why does it do so and how can i fix it?

Comment: vertical-align:top

Comment: @SahilDhir you mean it should be applied to the inline-block divs ;) ....

Comment: Exactly !!! @GCyrillus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `header h1` an `inline-block;` and assign it `vertical-align: middle;`, plus also assign `vertical-align: middle;` to the DIV that contains the `ul` with the social icons:

```css
header {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000032;
}

header div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header #social {
  float: left;
}

header li img {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

header img {
  display: block;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header h1 a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header #menu {
  float: right;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header class="row--no-gutter">
  <div class="col--1-of-3">
    <ul>
      <li id="social">
        <a href="#"><img src="../img/_f_logo_online/png/FB-f-Logo__blue_100.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
      </li>
      <li id="social">
        <a href="#"><img src="../img\Twitter_Starter_Kit\Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square/Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square_Color.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
      </li>
      <li id="social"></li>
      <li id="social"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col--1-of-3">
    <h1><a href="#">Lorem.</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col--1-of-3">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu">Om</li>
      <li id="menu">lorem1</li>
      <li id="menu">ipsun</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Exacly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `h1`'s parent element, the `div`:

```
header div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

since it behave like an inline-block things like this happen, change it to `block` to avoid this problem:

```css
header {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000032; 
}
  header div {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0; 
  }
  header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
  }
  header #social {
    float: left; 
  }
  header li img {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-right: 0; 
  }
  header img {
    display: block; 
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block; 
  }
  header h1 a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none; 
  }
  header #menu {
    float: right; 
  }

main {
  height: 100vh; 
}

.col--1-of-3 {

    float: left;
    }
```

```html
<header class="row--no-gutter">
    <div class="col--1-of-3">
      <ul>
        <li id="social"><a href="#"><img src="../img/_f_logo_online/png/FB-f-Logo__blue_100.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li id="social"><a href="#"><img src="../img\Twitter_Starter_Kit\Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square/Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square_Color.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
        <li id="social"></li>
        <li id="social"></li>
      </ul>
    </div><div class="col--1-of-3">
      <h1><a href="#">Lorem.</a></h1>
    </div><div class="col--1-of-3">
      <ul>
        <li id="menu">Om</li>
        <li id="menu">lorem1</li>
        <li id="menu">ipsun</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
  </header>
```

Also you have to use `float: left` in order to keep the structure of the layout

Comment: But the thing is i think i need inline-block. Because i need them to be a third of the screen. How else can I do so that divs are a third each?

Answer (score 0):

Your `header div` rule sets `display: inline-block;` and inline elements have a default vertical alignment of `baseline`. Try changing it to `top` instead.

Also note that your IDs must be unique.

```css
header {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000032;
}

header div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align:top;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header #social {
  float: left;
}

header li img {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

header img {
  display: block;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

header h1 a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header #menu {
  float: right;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header class="row--no-gutter">
  <div class="col--1-of-3">
    <ul>
      <li id="social">
        <a href="#"><img src="../img/_f_logo_online/png/FB-f-Logo__blue_100.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
      </li>
      <li id="social">
        <a href="#"><img src="../img\Twitter_Starter_Kit\Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square/Twitter_Social_Icon_Rounded_Square_Color.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
      </li>
      <li id="social"></li>
      <li id="social"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col--1-of-3">
    <h1><a href="#">Lorem.</a></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col--1-of-3">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu">Om</li>
      <li id="menu">lorem1</li>
      <li id="menu">ipsun</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```